# Maven jaxb2:xjc/jaxws:wsimport to be added in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2

I have a library I am creating based on some WSDL/XSD definitions.  I am having a problem having the compiled classes added in the eclipse project.  I can see that with a 'mvn compile' that the .class files are generated, as well as the .java files.  The problem is that even though the .class files are generated, eclipse is still showing an error on the import statement "import com.whatever.SomeService_Service" that was generated by one of the plugins.  I tried forcing the source to go into the project/src/main/java directory, but when the project is cleaned, it deletes files that I have created.  Has anyone run into this before/found a way to get it to recognize that the class files are there?  Thanks.

Comment: Are you creating the Eclipse project with `mvn eclipse:eclipse`? Where are the generated .java files put by the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention with Maven is to generate code in `target/generated-sources/<tool>`, for example `target/generated-sources/jax-ws`.

Once generated, run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` if you are using the maven eclipse plugin or **right-click** on your project and select **Maven > Update Project Configuration** if you are using M2Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing this is a old thread but only for reference, I resolved the problem with the following connector:

http://code.google.com/p/jaxws-maven-connector/